# Is there an option to show all test descriptions when I run jest tests?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, create-react-app

I'm using jest and enzyme with my create-react-app project. When I run `npm test`, I get an output that shows the names of the test files that passed but I'd like the output to also include the names of the tests.

Example:

Button.test.js

```
it ('renders button', () => {
    const button = shallow(<Button type="save"/>);
    expect(toJson(button)).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Right now when I run npm test the output is just:

> PASS  src/Button.test.js"

and the number of passed and failed tests (when the tests are successful). I would like the output to include "renders button" and any other test descriptions (like how the output looks when an rspec test is run).

Answer (score 253):

From [Jest's command-line options docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html)

> --verbose
>
> Display individual test results with the test suite hierarchy.

So running

```
jest --verbose
```

Will print all the names in `describe`, `it`, `test` blocks.
If you're running tests with `yarn`, you can do

```
yarn test --verbose
```

If you're running tests with `npm`, you can do

```
npm test -- --verbose
```

If you want to make this default, change your test script in `package.json`

```
"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom --verbose",
```

Now both `yarn test` and `npm test` should show all test names.

Answer (score 43):

Note that, instead of

```sh
jest --verbose
```

you can also **set `verbose` to `true` in `jest.config.js`**:

```js
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  ...
  verbose: true,
}
```

Comment: adding it to `jest.config.js ` is the only way to do it when using vue cli 4 and running `npm run test:unit`

Answer (score 28):

The `--verbose` flag sounds like it might do what you are looking for. According to the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/cli.html#verbose), it displays individual test results.

Comment: i tried using this and the output doesn't appear to be any different

Comment: What is the contents of your npm script and jest config?

Comment: @Sendai remember to add two hyphens to escape from `npm` arguments to `jest` arguments - like so: `npm test -- --verbose`. (Otherwise, the `--verbose` argument goes to `npm`, and you're seeing verbose `npm` output rather than verbose `jest` output.)

Comment: You can also add this value for example `jest --verbose` for the key `test` in your **package.json** and run `npm run test` in your terminal. This also worked for me fine.

Answer (score 10):

I was having the same issue with create-react-app (using both jest and enzyme), but was able to get the tests to appear after appending the existing `test` script in package.json with `--verbose=true`. So it now appears `"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom --verbose=true"`

Answer (score 4):

after doing this configuration in package.json( `"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom --verbose"`,) try running your test by **`npm test`**.

Note : with npm run test description is not reflecting for me as well.