# View console.log's in terminal and view each test description using jest and enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, console.log

I am currently running a few simple jest test suites to familiarize myself with these test in a react application, all located in a `__tests__` directory in the frontend directory of my program.
The complication I am running into: when I have multiple test files, jest will run each test file and the output will show whether or not I am passing the entire suite but not each individual `it` block in the suite. I am using the --watch flag to monitor *only* files that have changed since my latest git commit. I can fix this by using the suggestion from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50497630/is-there-an-option-to-show-all-test-descriptions-when-i-run-jest-tests) however when I set `"verbose": true` in my `jest` config inside `package.json` I no longer can view the console.log's in the terminal. When I change this to `"verbose": false` I can view the console.log's but I can no longer see all of the test descriptions and which ones are passing/failing.

Is there any way to view **both** the console.log's from each `it` block *and* each test's description in my console?

`"verbose": false`:

[image: console.log appearing, test descriptions not appearing]

`"verbose": true`:

[image: console.log not appearing, test descriptions appearing]

Comment: update: _SOME_ console.log's are appearing... `console.log('hi')` is NOT appearing, but `console.log(wrapper.debug())` IS appearing. `wrapper` here is a shallow mounted component.