# Jest dont show tests when there are more than one suite

Tags: express, testing, jestjs, command-line-interface, tdd

Im testing my app.
When I run 'npm test' I want to see in the terminal all tests.
I have one file called auth.test.js with all my tests.

So my output when i run npm test is this one:

```
> jest --forceExit

 PASS  src/test/auth.test.js
  /LOGIN testing
    ✓ Should not login a unexistent username. (22ms)
    ✓ Should not login with incorrect credentials. (63ms)
    ✓ Should not login with empty fields. (2ms)
    ✓ Should login a moked user. (67ms)
  /SIGNUP testing
    ✓ Should not sign up a new user with invalid password. (3ms)
    ✓ Should not sign up a new user with invalid username. (2ms)
    ✓ Should sign up a new user. (72ms)
    ✓ Should not sign up a existing user. (4ms)
    ✓ Should not sign up with empty fields. (3ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       9 passed, 9 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.114s, estimated 2s
Ran all test suites.
```

Thats fine. I can see all tests with details.

Now, I want to add a new file with tests, called api.tests.js.

Then, when I run 'npm test' i see this output:

```
> jest --forceExit

 PASS  src/test/api.test.js
 PASS  src/test/auth.test.js

Test Suites: 2 passed, 2 total
Tests:       10 passed, 10 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.589s, estimated 2s
Ran all test suites.
```

After read the jest documentation (cli article) I cant found how to see the details, like I see when testing 1 file,  but when testing more than 1 file.

Is it posible? How to do it?

Comment: [`--verbose`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#verbose)?

Comment: no, that is another kind of information, but not details of the test from what i pasted

Answer (score 2):

You're probably getting `npm --verbose` results which look different. To get `jest --verbose`, add two hyphens to your command: `-- --verbose`. I had the same problem and it worked for me.

I got the solution from here: [Is there an option to show all test descriptions when I run jest tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50497630/is-there-an-option-to-show-all-test-descriptions-when-i-run-jest-tests)

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. Tried the other config thing. It didn’t do anything. Sure seems like output is condensed after suite one.

Answer (score 1):

You need modify the configuration of [testMatch](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testmatch-array-string) in your `jest.config.js` file.

> The glob patterns Jest uses to detect test files. By default it looks for .js, .jsx, .ts and .tsx files inside of **tests** folders, as well as any files with a suffix of .test or .spec (e.g. Component.test.js or Component.spec.js). It will also find files called test.js or spec.js.

Your new test file named `api.tests.js`, so you need add a glob pattern

`'**/?(*.)+(specs|tests).[jt]s?(x)'` into the `testMatch` configuration.

For example, `jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'enzyme',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['jest-enzyme'],
  testEnvironmentOptions: {
    enzymeAdapter: 'react16'
  },
  coverageReporters: ['json', 'text', 'lcov', 'clover'],
  testMatch: ['**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)', '**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)', '**/?(*.)+(specs|tests).[jt]s?(x)']
};
```

Unit test result:

```sh
☁  jest-codelab [master] ⚡  npm t

> jest-codelab@1.0.0 test /Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab
> jest --detectOpenHandles

 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58663681/api.tests.js
  ✓ t1 (4ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.883s
Ran all test suites.
```

Comment: Here in this case the OP may have a typo in the name of his test file. But in my case, I've a folder tests, and inside that, I've 2 files, routes.test.js and api.test.js. As OP told, if I run only one of the file, by removing the other, I get status of each tests inside that file. But if I have both of them for testing I'm only getting PASS status with Big letters, before the file name but status of each tests are not showing.